# transport row data into column on oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

i have below data (table 1 ) , i want to transport  them as my second table (table 2) on oracle database, please help me on that .

table (1)

```
PRODUCT  COUNT         DATE
Pepsi    379         30/05/2017
Cola     220         30/05/2017
Pepsi    351         31/05/2017
Cola     123         31/05/2017
```

table (2)

```
DATE            Pepsi     Cola   
30/05/2017       379       220
31/05/2017       351       123
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a basic conditional aggregation query.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Old Style pivot:

```
select date
, max(decode(product, 'Pepsi', count, null) as Pepsi
, max(decode(product, 'Cola', count, null) as Cola
from <table 1>
group by date
;
```

11g has a pivot command which does similar (you can look it up).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Pivot`

```
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT DATE, PRODUCT, COUNT FROM PRODUCT)
  PIVOT
  (
    AVG(COUNT)
    FOR PRODUCT IN ('Pepsi' AS Pepsi, 'Cola' AS Cola)
  )
```

This works for me.